# Scrapy end/close conditions

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape

I'm trying to understand the stop conditions of the scrapy framework. Can someone explain it to me? I'm looking for the big picture.

So far I know that:

1. There are some queue or pool of urls to be scraped/parsed with parse
   methods. You can specify, bind the url to a specific method or let
   the default 'parse' do the job.
2. Within those methods you must return/yield another requests or items
3. You can raise manually an exception or get a signal out side (that you must capture)

Comment: That's about it. And when no more requests are returned or yielded in callbacks, Scrapy engine ends